# Is it possible to suspend a coroutine with a timeout?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What I want is a function like this:

```
suspendCoroutineWithTimeout(timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit, crossinline block: (Continuation<T>) -> Unit)
```

That does basically the same thing as the existing [`suspendCoroutine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html) function but if the callback or whatever was provided in the block dosen't get called within the specified timeout the corutine continues but with a TimeoutException or something like that.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can combine `withTimeout` and `suspendCancellableCoroutine` in a straightforward way for the desired effect:

```
suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutineWithTimeout(
    timeout: Long, unit: TimeUnit,
    crossinline block: (Continuation<T>) -> Unit
) = withTimeout(timeout, unit) {
    suspendCancellableCoroutine(block = block)
}
```

Comment: You might also change 'Continuation' to 'CancellableContinuation' (to improve upon the question).

Comment: how do you use this???? i am trying to understand how to use this with a function lets say requestInfoFromServer(param:String, callback: uglyCallbackClass)
have you an example where i can use the callback with this? or even without the callback? 
Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I am using it in unit tests ( = runTest ) means TestCoroutineContext and I see timeout is triggered almost immediately, albeit time is set to quite high. Is it a feature of test context? Could not find references about this behaviour so far.

Answer (score 14):

Perfect answer from @Roman Elizarov.. Just adding my 2 cents on it because I needed a return from that call.. So adding T? return it would be ...

```
suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutineWithTimeout(timeout: Long, crossinline block: (Continuation<T>) -> Unit ) : T? {
    var finalValue : T? = null
    withTimeoutOrNull(timeout) {
        finalValue = suspendCancellableCoroutine(block = block)
    }
    return finalValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutineWithTimeout(
    timeout: Long,
    crossinline block: (CancellableContinuation<T>) -> Unit
): T? {
    var finalValue: T? = null
    withTimeoutOrNull(timeout) {
        finalValue = suspendCancellableCoroutine(block = block)
    }
    return finalValue
}

suspend inline fun <T> suspendCoroutineObserverWithTimeout(
    timeout: Long,
    data: LiveData<T>,
    crossinline block: (T) -> Boolean
): T? {
    return suspendCoroutineWithTimeout<T>(timeout) { suspend ->
        var observers : Observer<T>? = null
        val oldData = data.value
         observers = Observer<T> { t ->
             if (oldData == t) {
                 KLog.e("参数一样,直接return")
                 return@Observer
             }
             KLog.e("参数不一样,刷新一波")
            if (block(t) && !suspend.isCancelled) {
                suspend.resume(t)
                observers?.let { data.removeObserver(it) }
            }
        }

        data.observeForever(observers)
        suspend.invokeOnCancellation {
            KLog.e("删除observiers")
            observers.let { data.removeObserver(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

The previous @Roman Elizarov and @febaisi answers have been answered very well, I added a type judgment and livedata on this basis, and I will return only when the conditions are met. Sorry, my English is not very good. –